# How with PhpStorm to work remotely using ssh?

Tags: phpstorm

From PhpStorm2021.1 I try to work with remote project using ssh

I found some video manual with Welcome page like : https://prnt.sc/7ucyiGyn3Rvz
but I did not found such page in my PhpStorm2021.1.
Where there is a way to connect to remote project using ssh

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1) https://www.jetbrains.com/remote-development/gateway/ 2) https://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2021/11/29/introducing-remote-development-for-jetbrains-ides/

Comment: You need 2021.3 version for this.